# spring hateoas hal-forms affordance support not working after upgrade to spring boot 3 due to jakarta.validation and hibernate version conflict

Tags: spring-hateoas

Spring Hateoas doesn't seem to be offering support for template affordance property validation in HAL-FORMS if you upgrade to Spring Boot 3. It seems to be Spring Boot moving to newer versions of hibernate and jakarta validation api's that Spring Hateoas PropertyUtils doesn't yet support. It's main branch is still importing javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, and its hibernate version conflicts with Spring boot 3.

Here's a 1 file (& pom) really simple example that demonstrates it working for Spring boot 2.7.6 (see commented out spring-boot-starter-parent version we'll use later.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <!-- <version>3.0.5</version> -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas-affordance-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-hateoas-affordance-sample</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
//import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Value;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL_FORMS)
public class SpringHateoasAffordanceSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringHateoasAffordanceSampleApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RestController
    class FooController {

        private static final String TEMPLATE = "Hello, %s!";

        @GetMapping("/")
        public HttpEntity<FooRepresentation> get(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "foo") String name) {

            var controller = methodOn(FooController.class);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new FooRepresentation(String.format(TEMPLATE, name))
                            .add(linkTo(controller.get(name)).withSelfRel())
                            .add(linkTo(controller.post(new FooModel("foo"))).withRel("foo"))
                    , HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        
        @PostMapping("/foo")
        public HttpEntity<FooModel> post(@RequestBody FooModel fooModel) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fooModel, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    
    @Value
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
    class FooRepresentation extends RepresentationModel<FooRepresentation> {
        private final String name;
    }
    
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class FooModel {
        
        @NotNull
        @Length(min = 2, max = 10)
        private String name;
    }
}
```

If I run the above and point my browser at http://localhost:8080 I get the 'required=true' and length min & max I expect for my FooModel.name property. I've had to adjust the urls as stack overflow thinks they're spam

```
{
    "name": "Hello, foo!",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/?name=foo"
        },
        "foo": {
            "href": "/foo"
        }
    },
    "_templates": {
        "default": {
            "method": "POST",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "required": true,
                    "minLength": 2,
                    "maxLength": 10,
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],
            "target": "/foo"
        }
    }
}
```

But if I upgrade to Spring 3.0.5 (see commented out line in the pom) I have to change the import to be jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull instead of javax.validation.constraints.NotNull but when I repeat my test I get a response that is missing the annotation driven hints.

```
{
    "name": "Hello, foo!",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/?name=foo"
        },
        "foo": {
            "href": "/foo"
        }
    },
    "_templates": {
        "default": {
            "method": "POST",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],
            "target": "/foo"
        }
    }
}
```

Although its not so obvious with the @Length that comes in from hibernate (the import package doesn't change) I suspect a version conflict is the cause for this too.

Is there some config I can use to work around, or are plans to support this in spring boot 3 planned?